# Strange product quantity behavior in OpenCart 2.0

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I'm evaluating OpenCart and it seems to be a competent tool to use as a e-store. However, I have a problem regarding the quantity of the products. Just to make sure I haven't done anything wrong, I just made a clean install.

Here's what I've tested:

I installed OpenCart 2.0.0.0 and changed the following:

- Order Status: Processing
- Processing Order Status: Processing
- Complete Order Status: Complete

Then I changed some settings for a default product (iPhone).

- Quantity for the product is set to 30. (Subtract stock: Yes)
- I added two options as checkboxes ("Checkbox 1" and "Checkbox 2") which have the quantity of 15 each. (Subtract stock: Yes)

I then added an iPhone to the cart (checking "Checkbox 1") and checked out with the "Cash On Delivery" option.
Now, the order was placed and the status is Pending. The quantity was not changed yet.
I added a order history with status Processing which decreased the quantity both the product and the option ("Checkbox 1").

All is fine until now. Now I'm adding the order history with status Processed. This resets the quantity. Yesterday when I did somewhat the same, the quantity was decreases once for every order history I added.

Am I doing something wrong here? I really need the quantity to work.

Bonus questions:

1. Is there a way to change the options' names (from "Checkbox 1" to "White" and "Checkbox 2" to "Black" for example)?
2. How do I change so that the status becomes "Processing" when a customer checks out?

Comment: Yes, I am also getting these functionality fault

Answer (score 0):

In admin>system>settings edit your store and go to the "Option" tab.
Under "Checkout" you have:
"Processing Order Status" and "Complete Order Status".
These two let you choose, respectively, at which status the stock should be subtracted and at which status the order should be considered as complete.

In your case if you want the status of a completed order to be "Processed" then you have to change the "Complete Order Status" to "Processed".

For the other two questions:

1) To change the checkbox names go to Catalog>Options in your admin dashboard. There you can either edit an already existing option or create a new one.

2) Each checkout option can have different processing statuses. These can be changed accordingly in their respective settings in the Admin>Extentions>Payments.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I edited my answer accordingly.